# JWT tokens creation from AAD -Azure APIM to call backend API

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-api-management, bearer-token

I am in a situation where dev portal login is enabled by AAD login and while using the "try it" option in devportal, since the AAD login is already is there any way we can create the JWT token with logged in user credential and pass the bearer token to the backend API, so that user doesn't need to worry about the token.
So far I have only seen the JWT token validator for validating the taken in the header.
Any suggestion of guidance is highly appreciated